# Differences in benchmarking two packages?

Tags: serialization, benchmarking, protocol-buffers, thrift

I'm a student(noob) tasked with benchmarking googles protocol buffers and apache thrift serialization packages.

My issue is that in Apache Thrift THREE calls are made to serialize to string... but in google protocol buffers only ONE call is made.

The three apache thrift calls are to set up memory before serializing.

Should I include those memory setup functions in my benchmark for apache thrift to be equivalent to the google call?

Are there any guide posts or best practices for benchmarking something like this?

```
#apache thrift
person1 = Person()
person1.name = "person1"
person1.id = 1
person1.email = "test@test.com"
#three calls
transportOut = TTransport.TMemoryBuffer()
protocolOut = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transportOut)
person1.write(protocolOut)



#google protocol
person1 = Person()
person1.name="person1"
person1.id=1
person1.email="test@test.com"
#one call
person1.SerializeToString()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact use of the API can indeed make a huge difference in benchmark performance, although whether it is one calls or three is not necessarily the central issue.  For example, in Protobuf-C++, you can use `SerializeToString()` to get an `std::string`, but if you are ultimately writing that string to a file, it may be faster to use `SerializeToFileDescriptor()`.  You need to be careful to use the best API for the job in order to create a fair benchmark.

In Python (which it looks like you are using), there is no other way to serialize than to a string.  However, there is `SerializePartialToString()` which skips checking whether required are present.  Using this may have a performance impact, since it does less work.  Whether or not dropping that work is "fair" is highly debatable -- many apps actually do not want required field checking, but others do.  This is where benchmarks get really murky.

I imagine Thrift has similar issues, though I'm not very familiar with its API.

Ultimately you need to carefully study the APIs that are available, decide what specific use case you want to target, and then choose what you think is most appropriate for that case.

To answer your specific question, though, I think you *should* include all setup that is specific to the particular message instance.  An apples-to-apples comparison should include all per-message-instance setup and teardown.

BTW, be sure to try enabling the [C-extension-backed Protobuf-Python implementation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#cpp_impl) (bottom of page).  It's a whole lot faster.  Of course, this brings up another use case question:  are you imagining a case where C extensions are allowed?  For example, they are not allowed on AppEngine.  (BTW, I'm not sure if Thrift uses C extensions or not; you should check on that.)

It might be interesting to throw in a comparison with [Cap'n Proto](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/) while you're at it.  (Disclosure:  I am the author of Cap'n Proto in C++, and also (in the past) of Protobufs v2 in C++ and Java, but not of the Python versions in either case.)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. We ended up doing excactly what you said with the c backed proto extension.  We also did a 2 phase test with and without the object creation. The cbacked proto extension won over message pack and thrift to the point where we almost thought something was wrong with our experiment! The non cbacked proto extension was slower than json though which didn't fit our predictions either. It was an interesting experiment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are trying to benchmark it as part of an higher level solution. So it sounds only consequent to me to benchmark the whole thing, not just a part of it.

PS: Would be nice to learn about your findings, by the way.

Comment: Gladly!  I'll post all the code and results up on github when I'm done and post the link. My group and I are kind of a noobs at this but the results will be interesting and hopefully it can be refined.